# make an element appearing soflty

Tags: css, animation

I would like to reproduce the way each page appear on this website : https://arnaud-desportes.fr/

It must be something with the light. I try to catch the animation but it doesn't work that way.
Please help

Comment: "*It must be something with the light.*" - what does that mean? "*I try to catch the animation but it doesn't work that way.*" - how are you trying to "catch" an animation? "*Please help*" - if there were any way we could decipher your question, we possibly would. I'd strongly suggest you read: "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*," as your question doesn't describe what problem you're facing and has no code to (even try to) show what you want to do. Also, we don't write your code for you; we help you fix your code so that it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without being able to see some of the code that you're currently working with, it's kind of hard to be able to help you move in the right direction.

Some of what you're looking to do can be done with CSS. It looks like he may have put a background image in one of the  tabs.

Did you try looking at the developer tools to see if you can understand what he's using and why he's using it? I think that may be a best first step and then you can build from there.

Hope this helps a bit.

Also, please be kind as not everyone has english as a first language. It seems like he's trying to find a way to have the background image look like it does on the website with that blur.

You could also work with the item in PS and then bring it to the CSS through images.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Actually, I didn't write any code because I wouldn't know how to reproduce it and because it must be something classical for specialists.

Comment: I wish we agree on this because it would be I think a lost of time for me to try to reinvent the wheel. Are we ok that we are speaking about an effect which is appearing during the first second of the page and that is also affecting the whole page ? When I said that I tried to catch the animations, I was talking of the "Animations" tab of the chrome debugger (it is not installed by default) and thus I found nothing.

Comment: Is this technic of putting an image in an other tab familiar ? Do you have an example of it ?